# How to convert a line having string into dictionary using python?

Tags: file, dictionary, python-2.6

I have a line as:

```
Name:sample   Location:(xyz)
```

I want to to convert it to dictionary as follows:

```
{'Name':'sample','Location':'(xyz)'}
```

I want to do this using python script. So, please suggest how do i make this possible. The platform i am working on is linux.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # First split at whitespaces ==> ['Name:sample', 'Location:(xyz)']
 # Next split each item at ':' and convert them into list of tuples
 #    ==>[('Name', 'sample'), ('Location', '(xyz)')]
 # Convert the list of tuples to dictionary

sample_string       = "Name:sample   Location:(xyz)"

split_sample_string = sample_string.split()

tuple_string        = [tuple(item.split(":")) for item in split_sample_string]

final_dictionary = dict(tuple_string)

print final_dictionary
# final_dictionary = {'Name': 'sample', 'Location': '(xyz)'}
```